# Is it possible to find the vectors that span the nullspace of a large, symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, symbolic, linear-algebra

My problem is composed of two parts, a large sparse matrix $L$ ($m$x$n$ where $m=10^3$, and $n=10^5$, with $10^7$ non-zero complex numbers), and a dense, symbolic matrix $F$ ($m$x$m$ where $m=10^3$), which is the partial derivative of the outer product of a symbolic vector: $F = \partial_x ( A^TA ) $ where $A=\{1,x,y,z,x^2,xy,...\}$. Note that this leaves F with a very large null space whose dimension is $m-2$, and is actually very easy and fast to compute.

My problem is that I want to find the null space of $L^*FL$.

Further, it even doesn't have to be with *Mathematica* if there is a solution in another fashion. Is this computationally feasible? It isn't through just a conventional call since the computer runs out of memory just constructing $L^*FL$. Are there properties of matrices that I am overlooking that would be useful here?

Edit:
Specifically, $A$ is a vector of all powers of $x,y,z$ that form a power series up to some maximum total power, and $x,y,z$ are all real valued. Their ordering is not important.

Comment: $F$ is symmetric, then?

Comment: Yes, and the three unknown symbols ($x,y,z$) that comprise it are real valued.

Comment: Would it be feasible for you to generate the eigensystem of $F$?

Comment: Actually no. Well, not that I know of. The last two eigenvectors of $F$ - the ones that aren't in the nullspace - grow extremely fast as $A$ grows. It becomes infeasible to compute after $F$ is ~500x500.

Comment: Well, actually, I'm interested in the eigenvectors of $F$ that *are* in the nullspace. Can you generate them?

Comment: Yes. They are simple and quick to compute.

Comment: Just so you'll see what I'm seeing: consider the eigendecomposition $\mathbf F=\mathbf V^\ast\mathbf \Lambda\mathbf V$. Then, consider the congruence transformation $\mathbf L^\ast\mathbf F\mathbf L=\mathbf L^\ast\mathbf V^\ast\mathbf \Lambda\mathbf V\mathbf L=(\mathbf V\mathbf L)^\ast\mathbf \Lambda(\mathbf V\mathbf L)$. This leaves the *inertia* of your original matrix invariant.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. Well, inertia is new to me.

Comment: Inertia is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia). Your interest would be in the fact that the number of zero eigenvalues is left invariant under a congruence transformation. So, consider the null vectors multiplied by $\mathbf L$... ;)

Comment: I think you are suggesting that the eigenvectors would be preserved under a left multiplication. But doesn't the right multiplication scramble them? And at the end of the day I want nullspace of $L^*FL$ (which is of dimension $n$x$n$).

Comment: @J.M. what about the simpler route of determining whether the two eigenvectors of $\mathbf{F}$ that don't lie in its null-space also lie in the null space of $\mathbf{L}$? If they do, then doesn't the null-space of $\mathbf{L}^\ast\mathbf{F}\mathbf{L}$ span the entire space?

Comment: @rcollyer, now that you mention it, that is less effortful! Except… as mentioned in a previous comment, OP has difficulty generating the non-null eigenvectors for large dimensions…

Comment: @rcollyer If those vectors are also null then L^*FL is all zeros.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau quite right. So, I guess that's even simpler. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The null space is going to be a very large matrix. I'll show how to generate the space of nonnull vectors (I think that might be called the coimage or something like that).

I will demonstrate this method for dimensions 56 by 1000 (56 because that's how many xyz monomials there are through degree 5).

```
deg = 5;
monoms = Union[
   Flatten[Outer[Times, Sequence @@ Table[{1, x, y, z}, deg]]]];
amat = Outer[Times, monoms, monoms];
dabara = D[Transpose[amat].amat, x];
dims = {Dimensions[dabara][[1]], 10^3};
```

I'll make a 56x1000 sparse array with 1s in 56 random locations.

```
SeedRandom[123456789];
lmat = SparseArray[
   Thread[Transpose[{RandomInteger[{1, dims[[1]]}, dims[[1]]], 
       RandomInteger[{1, dims[[2]]}, dims[[1]]]}] -> 1], dims];
```

Now we can generate nonnull vectors just by checking (non)nullity of all the unit vectors. Ordinarily this would not work so well but for this size null space it seems fine.

```
Timing[
 nonnullgenerators = 
   Cases[Table[
     Transpose[lmat].(dabara.(lmat.UnitVector[dims[[2]], j])), {j, 
      dims[[2]]}], Except[{0 ..}]];]
Length[nonnullgenerators]

(* Out[155]= {16.56656, Null}

Out[156]= 54 *)
```

We can remove excess to get the generators by row reduction.

```
Timing[rred = RowReduce[nonnullgenerators];]
nonnullspace = Cases[rred, Except[{0 ..}]];
Length[nonnullspace]

(* Out[157]= {29.7926, Null}

Out[159]= 2 *)
```

When the dimensions get to the point where this is unwieldy, an alternative might be to interleave row reduction with finding nonnulls.

Comment: Wait, I am confused, this sounds like it will work for the non-null vectors, but I wanted the nullspace of $L^*FL$

Comment: Actually this is not even quite what I stated. It is the image, not coimage (I reduced the image vectors). So here is the question. How do you propose to describe the null space generators? For your dimensions there will be around 10^5 of them, and each will be of around that same length. That set could take up a lot of space. You can easily handle those that are simply unit vectors, describing by sparse matrices. But the others?